# How to add right (horizontal) arrow in jquery UI tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I am using the jQuery UI `tooltip` but I am not able to add right arrow to a  tooltip.

I am following [this link](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style)

I mean I am able to add top & bottom arrow, but not a right & left one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyBwU/695/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var position = { my: 'left center', at: 'right+10 center' };   
    position.collision = 'none';
    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip();
    $('input[value="right"]').trigger('change');
    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip('option', 'position', position);
    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', 'right');

});
```